# Linking ticks in a MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Is there a method of aligning tick labels?

I have a figure that has two y axes where the values vary greatly. I would like to align the tick labels so that each value shown on one y label matches up with a value on the opposite ylabel. For example:

```
data1 = 1+ (12-1).*rand(365,1);
data2 = 1 + (700-1).*rand(365,1);
time = 1:365;
figure(1);
ax1 = axes('position',[0.05 0.5 0.22 0.37]);
plot(time,data1,'k','linewidth',1);
ylabel('label 1');
pos=double(get(ax1,'position'));
ax2=axes('position',pos,'color','none','YAxisLocation','right','xtick',[])
hold on;
plot(time,data2,'r','linewidth',1,'parent',ax2);
ylabel(ax2,'label 2');
```

Here I would like the second y axis to have the same number of ticks as the first y axis as well as the same spacing between them. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plotyy` instead of `plot`, it handles this for you:

```
plotyy(time, data1, time, data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the y axis limits and tick locations explicitly:

```
ylim(ax1,[lowerBound upperBound])
set(ax1,'ytick',[tick1 tick2 tick3 tick4])
```

This can let you fine tune the tick locations for a particular plot. It makes zooming and panning less functional, since the ticks are often left behind.